# Creating triangle in java

Tags: java

I was trying to exercise on creating triangles. However, I realy find this diffucult to implement. Can you give me a way to complete it?

```
    5
   545
  54345
 5432345
543212345
```

ops! you're so tough. you down vote a lot!
here is the code that I tried to do something but the only true thing is the calculation of spaces.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = n; j > i; j--) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    //left
    for (int j = i; j > 1; j--) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    //right
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
       System.out.print(j + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code writing request.

Comment: Did you write any code?

Comment: No i'm not request to write the code. I want to discuss about the way that I can implement.

Comment: Please show us that your have tried something and we will help you correct the errors !

Comment: Give us proof that you made an effort. How would you start? Write pseudocode, or a few paragraphs epxlaining how to do it logically.

Comment: there are tons of code on google with these kind of patterns. you shall check them out and understand how they are made. than you will be able to write your own as well

Comment: @user3646090 Though discussing implementation is a noble thing, this isn't really the right forum for that. This is meant to be a strict question and answer system, to which you don't have an actual question. "I tried this and can't figure it out" questions are okay, but you need to really at least represent what you tried and the thought process behind it. Anyway, I've provided a very vague answer that will hopefully help you get somewhere.

Comment: I show my work, why do I still get down votes?

Comment: I updated, it prints as 1 121 32123. i guess the problem is in the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this simple algorithm gives you an idea of how you could solve this problem step by step.

```
int n = 5;

// We go line by line
for (int line=0; line<n; line++) {

    // Calculate number of spaces in the line. Number of spaces on the 
    // right hand side is always the same as the number on the left hand side
    int spaces = n - line;

    // We have twice as much digits in each line as the line index plus one 
    // digit (because we always have an odd number of digits). 
    int digits = 2*line + 1;

    // Print left spaces
    for (int i=0; i<spaces; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    // Print digits. This does the trick.
    for (int i=0; i<digits; i++) {
        // The key for the algorithm is this symmetrical triangle. We will use 
        // digits/2 - i expression, which prints out the following triangle
        //      0
        //    1,0,-1
        //  2,1,0,-1,2
        // etc.
        //
        // Now we need to get rid of minus sign by using Math.abs function
        // and add number of spaces decreasing with every new line and 
        // compensating increasing digits in the triangle.
        System.out.print(spaces + Math.abs(digits/2 - i));
    }

    // Print right spaces. We may omit this, as right spaces are not 
    // visible and they have no impact on the shape.
    for (int i=0; i<spaces; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    // Finish the line
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look for some patterns.

Row 1 starts with 4(5-1) spaces. Row 2 with 3 spaces ... last row with no spaces.

Row 1 Has just the highest number once. Row 2 has highest, second highest, highest. The last row starts with highest, and prints down to 1, then back up to the highest.

If you write your code to work with these general cases, then it will probably work.

Comment: I cannot find 545 and in the next line 54345. edit: I edited my code.

Comment: I updated the code, it prints as 1 121 32123. i guess the problem is in the limits, how can I change?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
def makeTriangle(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(" "*(n-i), end="")
        for j in range(0, i):
            print(n-j, end="")
        for j in range(i, -1, -1):
            print(n-j, end="")
        print(" "*(n-i))
```

I have tested the above code, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Or at least, it works perfectly in [tag:python3]...

Comment: I updated the code, it prints as 1 121 32123. i guess the problem is in the limits, how can I change?