# Number Pyramid like Egyptian with decreasing numbers

Tags: java, numbers

Im working on a pyramid on Java. I did it with stars. But i want to do it with decreasing numbers. I'm using an input. Assume input is 5;

```
    5
   545
  54345
 5432345
543212345
```

My code is;

```
int size = 11; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i=i+2) {
        int spaceCount = (size - i)/2;
        for(int j = 0; j< size; j++) {
            if(j < spaceCount || j >= (size - spaceCount)) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I'm very glad to for your attention. Thanks a lot.

```
int size = 11; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i=i+2) {
        int spaceCount = (size - i)/2;
        for(int j = 0; j< size; j++) {
            if(j < spaceCount || j >= (size - spaceCount)) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(n);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: You are only printing stars and spaces at the moment.

Comment: I want to do it without stars. I want to do it which i showed in question.

Comment: @user3647819 Ok and what have you tried to print the numbers instead of the stars?

Comment: this smells assignment.

Comment: @ZouZou I couldn't find any algorithm with this. If i try something with numbers, i can't run the program.

Comment: @user3647819 Show us the code with your attempt at printing the numbers and the errors that the code produce.

Comment: 'int size = 11; 
     for (int i = 1; i <= size; i=i+2) {
         int spaceCount = (size - i)/2;
         for(int j = 0; j< size; j++) {
             if(j < spaceCount || j >= (size - spaceCount)) {
                 System.out.print(" ");
             } else {
                 System.out.print(n);
             }
         }
         System.out.println();
     }'

Comment: @user3647819 Put that into your question

Comment: @user3580294 i did right now

Comment: What's `n`? Of course your program doesn't compile if you use a variable without defining it anywhere

Comment: what is wrong with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703886/creating-triangle-in-java

Comment: @user3580294 System.out.print(n-j+1) im using this for output. I couldn't find any algorithm for this like i told. If i do it, my program gives a logical error.

Comment: *But what is `n`*? You never defined what `n` is. Read the error messages that are emitted by your compiler. They give you a *very* good idea of what you messed up. And the idea of this exercise isn't for you to go find an algorithm that does the work for you. The idea is to make you *think* and figure out the answer on your own

Comment: @lakshman thank you very much for your time, finally my program works, thank you god for all these good people that have been helping me to cross thıs hard bridge that has been long for a time, i wanna thank my mom for gave me birth and thats it, thank you tatals.

Comment: ...And that's exactly how you *don't* learn...

Comment: user3647819: if you got your time little bit to think and to search google you could find the answer to your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?
But this only works for numbers of 1 - 9.

```
int h = 2;
String spacing = h == 1 ? "" : String.format("%" + (h - 1) + "s", "");

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(h));

System.out.printf("%s%s\n", spacing, s);
for(int i = h; i > 1; --i){
    System.out.print(spacing.substring(0, i - 2));
    s.insert(s.length() / 2 + 1, String.valueOf(i - 1) + String.valueOf(i));
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}
```